# EKS pod not able to communicate to anther service through cluserip or nodeport

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have service(pod) in eks namely "abc", which need to communicate to another pod in same cluster named "activity".

We have configured a clusterip service to stand in between.

While trying to connect to the application from the pod of abc its working through cluster ip service.

```
    root@abc-5d8d95fb44-5w7ff:/# curl --location --request GET 'http://clusterip-service:8080/internal/xml/ping'
 "message" : "PING OK from Internal"
```

But when trying from outside

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://domain/service/abc/ping?debug=true&activity=Internal' 
{"errorCode":"","errorMessage":""}%
```

and getting an error

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 503 Service Unavailable
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
at com..campaign.controller.PingController.pingActivityInternal(PingController.java:179)
at com.campaign.controller.PingController.handlePing(PingController.java:104)
```

The java code is

```
public ResponseEntity<Map> handlePing(@RequestParam(required = false) String debug,
        @RequestParam(value = "activity", required = false, defaultValue = "No") String activity) throws UnknownHostException {
    logger.debug("Processing ping request...");
    final HashMap<String, String> ping = new HashMap<>();
    logger.info("Starting Ping debugging Activityping Debug[{}]",debug);
    logger.info("Starting Ping debugging Activity activity[{}]",activity);

    if (activity.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
        pingActivity();
        ping.put("message", "PING OK from Activity..");
    }else if (activity.equalsIgnoreCase("Internal")) {
        pingActivityInternal();
        ping.put("message", "PING OK from Activity Internal..");
```

and the function is called

```
public static void pingActivityInternal() {
    try {
        logger.info("Starting Ping Internal Activity");

        final String activityUrl = "http://clusterip-service:8080/internal/xml/ping";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the service externally, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network-load-balancing.html) for example.

Comment: But thats an internal call

Comment: But thats an internal call  and the communication is going through clusterip